# the probability that a patient recovers from a rare blood disease

Tags: probability

The probability that a patient recovers from a rare blood disease is 0.4.. if 15 people are known to have contracted this disease what is the probability that

(a) at least 10 survive

(b) from 3 to 8 survive

(c) exactly 5 survive

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @fgp i tried but it seems to be wrong especially when others answered

Comment: @LobnaMagdy Please include what you tried. Otherwise you will get noone to help you...;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A)  15C10 * (0.4)^10 * (1-0.4)^5 + 15C11 * (0.4)^11 * (1-0.4)^4 + 15C12 * (0.4)^12 * (1-0.4)^3 + 15C13 * (0.4)^13 * (1-0.4)^2 + 15C14 (0.4)^14 * (1-0.4) + 15C15 * (0.4)^15

Answer (score 4):

@Lobna Magdy;

c)

$$ (1-p)^{15-n} p^n \binom{15}{n} $$

n = number that survive.

p = 4 / 10.

$$P(\text{exactly 5 survive})=\left (1-\frac{4}{10}  \right )^{15-5} \left (\frac{4}{10}  \right )^5 \binom{15}{5} =\frac{5674372704}{30517578125}\\ \\ \approx .185937844764672 $$

You do one...

Answer (score 2):

You should use the binomial distribution. The probability that at least 10 people survive is:

$$P(X\geq 10) = P(X=10) + P(X=11) + P(X=12) + P(X=13)+P(X=14)+P(X=15)=\displaystyle{\sum _{n=10}^{15} \binom{15}{n} 0.4^{n} \cdot (1-0.4)^{15-n}}$$

Since using the bonomial distribution, $P(X=k)=\binom{15}{k} 0.4^k \cdot (1-0.4)^{15-k}$.

Comment: Why binomial distribution is used? Just to understand answer